# Dropping rows based on multi-index condition / character in Pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas, hierarchical-data, multi-index

The dataframe below is a multi-indexed dataframe with hierarchical columns (df):

```
                   EMG                                     Biofeedback    
Time     ID  
                   delta theta alpha beta high beta gamma  HeartRateVariabilty GSR     
20170101 PD102       4     5     8    3         0     9                1        2 
20170102 PD102       5     7     8    4         6     5                2        3       
20170101 SS104-1     3     4     4    5         2     4                8        2
20170101 SS104       3     4     3    4         2     4                8        2
```

How can i drop all rows that contain '-' (a dash) in the index i.e drop SS104-1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `boolean mask` created by[`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), last invert it by `~`:

```
print (~df.index.get_level_values('ID').str.contains('-'))
[ True  True False  True]

df1 = df[~df.index.get_level_values('ID').str.contains('-')]
print (df1)
                 EMG                                          Biofeedback    
               delta theta alpha beta high beta gamma HeartRateVariabilty GSR
Time     ID                                                                  
20170101 PD102     4     5     8    3         0     9                   1   2
20170102 PD102     5     7     8    4         6     5                   2   3
20170101 SS104     3     4     3    4         2     4                   8   2
```